# Set value of state to clicked button's value

Tags: javascript, reactjs, state, use-state

I am trying to have my `state` be set to which of 2 buttons the user presses.

```
 const [pizzaSize, setPizzaSize] = useState(null);
const changePizza = (e) => {
setPizzaSize(e.target.value)
}
```

```
<button type="button" onClick={() => changePizza()}>Medium</button>
```

This is throwing the following error `TypeError: Cannot read property 'target' of undefined`
I understand that I am not doing this correctly but I can't figure out how to set the state to the the value of the button that is clicked.

My full code is  [here](https://github.com/Imstupidpleasehelp/pizzaPiza/blob/main/src/CYO.js) in case it is needed.

Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to give value property to your button which is right now set to undefined and pass the event to handler Function

```
<button type="button" value = "Medium"  onClick={(e) => changePizza(e)}>Medium</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can even pass the function directly and the event param will b passed automatically to `changePizza`

```
<button type="button" value = "Medium"  onClick={changePizza}>Medium</button>
```

Or you can directly do this

```
<button type="button" value = "Medium"  onClick={(e) =>setPizzaSize(e.target.value)}>Medium</button>
```